# how do I change the order of rows in GrapheneDB node?

Tags: neo4j, graphenedb

my nodes have the following order in GrapheneDB neo4J hosted database:

```
<id>:3 human_date:Wednesday, July 5, 2017type:painuuid:7c74a49d-f102-4825-914b-87dcc88d339bvalue:Emptinessepoch_utc_i:1499285499
```

The input of the JSON object is I first create the node with the `value`, and then set properties: {uuid, epoch_utc, human_time}

It's hard to use the graphical UI to see different nodes because only `human_time` is displayed...and that is often the same for multiple nodes.  I would prefer to see `type` or `value`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the properties that were picked by Neo4j Browser to be displayed as captions.

Just click at the top of the window on a Label tag, and once selected, change the caption at the bottom to `type` or `value`.

For more advanced styling, like displaying multiple captions, you can edit the Graph Style Sheet (.grass file). Just enter `:style` in Neo4j Browser, click on the download icon, edit and upload the file back and the changes will be reflected.

You can read more on Neo4j Browser styling [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/).

[image]